# Airport Express difference between MC414LL/A and MC414Z/A?

Tags: airport

I can't seem to find the details on Apple's website, but I have seen both model numbers `MC414LL/A` and `MC414Z/A` for sale at various web shops.

The [english wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPort_Express#Models) only lists the `LL/A` variant and the [german wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_AirPort#AirPort_Express) has only the `Z/A` model.

Is it perhaps just the difference between US and European models?

Comment: Pure guess, but it's likely to be which WiFi channels can be enabled. There are different rules in US/EU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is to do with the difference between the power cable shipped with it and possibly some regional legal restrictions.

The model number is `MC414`.

- `MC414Z/A` is the European variant.
- `MC414LL/A` is the US variant.
- `MC414C/A` is the Canadian variant.
- `MC414J/A` is the Japanese variant.
- `MC414B/A` is the UK variant.

etc...

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Research and 6.5 years working in an Apple Store